# Detect if ctrl key is pressed

Tags: macos, javascript-automation

In JavaScript for Automation (JXA), we can detect if the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> key is pressed with

```
ObjC.import("Cocoa")
$.NSEvent.modifierFlags & $.NSControlKeyMask
```

If <kbd>ctrl</kbd> is not pressed, the return will be `0`. If it is, the value will be different.

But [`NSControlKeyMask` is deprecated](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nscontrolkeymask). I found [`NSEventModifierFlagControl`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nseventmodifierflags/nseventmodifierflagcontrol) but can’t get it to work.

What is the current way to detect if the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> key is pressed?

Comment: Just because it is deprecated doesn't mean it won't work. Did this code stop working? If not there is no urgent need to update it. Functions can be deprecated for years before they are removed. 

When you say it doesn't work what happens? Does it compile? if so, what is the value that the '&' operator is returning? Does it always return 0?

Comment: @ⱮarkƬ It means it always returns the same value, but I’m not even sure I’m using it correctly, hence the vagueness. The urgency of wanting to update the code doesn’t factor into it. It has already been deprecated for over two years, and I’ll only know if it stopped working after I upgrade my system (which is over two years behind). Postponing updating deprecated code is an accident waiting to happen. I’d rather have it correct now than have it break from under me when I really need it.

Comment: @user137369 Please post the full code on how you register for and get the event. It is hard to diagnose the problem without seeing your actual code.

Comment: @jksoegaard That is the full code. Those two lines are all there is to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per your latest comment, you state that the code you have quoted works in practice, and your only problem is you want to get rid of the deprecated NSControlKeyMask.

Simply replace that word with NSEventModifierFlagControl and this is it.

The only thing Apple did is to change the name. In recent macOS NSControlKeyMask is even defined as simply being equal to NSEventModifierFlagControl. Both have the value 1 << 18 (i.e. the 18th bit is set to 1, rest is 0).

Comment: There’s nothing wrong with the presented code. That code is, as stated, working. It doesn’t do anything with the condition for simplicity of the question, **but it does return different codes, which proves it works**. What I’m asking for is the method to replace the deprecated one.

Comment: You're contradicting yourself now. You replied to MarkT saying that it always returns the same value - now you're saying it returns different values. Without the correct information, it is hard to help you?

Comment: I have changed the answer so that it now has the correct answer according to your latest statement that your old code is in fact working, returning different values.

Comment: “You replied to MarkT saying that it always returns the same value”. That was in reply to “When you say it doesn't work what happens?”, which was referring to `NSEventModifierFlagControl`.

Comment: Okay, that doesn't really make any sense. Why ask if a constant would change? So you have basically misunderstood eachother. Anyways, I have given you the correct answer to the revised question now, so you can remove the downvote.